# How to refresh a QFileSystemModel in a QTreeView after files change through another process?

Tags: qt, qtreeview, qfilesystemmodel, qfilesystemwatcher

I have a `QTreeView` with a `QFileSystemModel` as the model.  Files and directories load correctly.

In my application workflow, a different process copies and overwrites files on the file system.

However, my `QTreeView` does not update the item/row for the overwritten file (eg: the size and lastModified values for the file do not update to the new values).

Using the file path, I'm able to get a `FileInfo` that DOES have the updated lastModified value.  However, using that *same path* to grab the `QModelIndex` of the row's lastModified value results in it returning the old value.

I've tried a few things (see below) to no avail.

PLEASE let me know if you are aware of how to resolve this.  Many Thanks! :)

```
// ... at this point the file system has been updated and the file
// has new values for things like last modified date
QFileInfo *updatedFile = new QFileInfo( filePath );

QModelIndex indexOfFileName = myFileTreeView->myFileSystemModel->index( filePath );
QModelIndex indexOfLastModifiedDate = myFileTreeView->myFileSystemModel->index( filePath, lastModifiedColumnIndex );

// attempts to kick the QFileSystemModel and QTreeView to update the model values
// a collection from the internet :)
emit myFileTreeView->dataChanged( indexOfFileName, indexOfLastModifiedDate );
emit myFileTreeView->myFileSystemModel->dataChanged( indexOfFileName, indexOfLastModifiedDate );
myTreeView->repaint();
myTreeView->update( indexOfLastModifiedDate );
myTreeView->viewport()->update();

// looking to see if values changed
QModelIndex newIndexOfLastModifiedDate = myTreeView->myFileSystemModel->index( filePath, lastModifiedColumnIndex );

// this shows the correct row and column for the index, so the index looks correct
qDebug() << "newIndexOfLastModifiedDate: " << newIndexOfLastModifiedDate;

// does not have new value
qDebug() << "newIndexOfLastModifiedDate.data(): " << newIndexOfLastModifiedDate->data();

// has new value
qDebug() << "fileInfo.lastModified(): " << updatedFile->lastModified();
```

**[EDIT - adding steps to simulate application workflow]**

The following I believe to be the steps that can mimic the issue.

**Steps to Reproduce:**

- Setup a simple QTreeView that uses a QFileSystemModel as its model.
- Set Root Path to a directory called `Root`
- Create a text file, `Test.txt` inside of the `Root` dir
- Load the application and observe in it the `Test.txt` file's *Last Modified Date* in the `Root` dir.
- **Keep this application window open.**
- Copy `Test.txt` to a *different* directory, say `Temp`
- Modify the file and save in `Temp`
- Copy and *Replace* `Test.txt` to overwrite the file in `Root` dir
- Observe the *Last Modified Date* in the application window

Result: The *Last Modified Date* is not updated

**ADDED SAPMLE:**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QFileSystemModel>
#include <QFile>
#include <QFileInfo>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTreeView>
#include <QDateTime>


// Globals
QFileSystemModel *model = NULL;
const QString name = "test.txt";
const int delayOffset = 1000;

// Interface
void onDataChanged( const QModelIndex& topLeft, const QModelIndex& bottomRight, const QVector< int >& roles );
void clean();
void doCreateFile();
void doUpdateFile();
void doTest();


// Implementation
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    QApplication a( argc, argv );
    int delay = 0;

    // Clean
    clean();

    // Init model
    const QString rootPath = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath();
    model = new QFileSystemModel( &a );
    model->setRootPath( rootPath );
    QObject::connect( model, &QFileSystemModel::dataChanged, &onDataChanged );

    // Init file actions
    delay += delayOffset * 2;
    QTimer tCreate;
    tCreate.setSingleShot( true );
    tCreate.setInterval( delay );
    QObject::connect( &tCreate, &QTimer::timeout, &doCreateFile );

    delay += delayOffset * 4;
    QTimer tUpdate;
    tUpdate.setSingleShot( true );
    tUpdate.setInterval( delay );
    QObject::connect( &tUpdate, &QTimer::timeout, &doUpdateFile );

    // GUI
    QTreeView w;
    w.setModel( model );
    w.setRootIndex( model->index( rootPath ) );
    w.show();
    w.expandAll();

    qDebug() << "Start";
    tCreate.start();
    tUpdate.start();

    return a.exec();
}

void onDataChanged( const QModelIndex& topLeft, const QModelIndex& bottomRight, const QVector< int >& roles )
{
    qDebug() << "Model changed";
}

void clean()
{
    const QString path = QString( "%1/%2" ).arg( QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() ).arg( name );
    QFile f( path );

    if ( f.exists() )
        f.remove();
}

void doCreateFile()
{
    const QString path = QString( "%1/%2" ).arg( QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() ).arg( name );
    QFile f( path );

    if ( !f.open( QIODevice::WriteOnly ) )
    {
        qDebug() << "Could not create file";
        return ;
    }

    f.write( "Preved" );
    f.close();

    qDebug() << "File created";
    doTest();
}

void doUpdateFile()
{
    const QString path = QString( "%1/%2" ).arg( QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() ).arg( name );
    QFile f( path );

    if ( !f.open( QIODevice::Append ) )
    {
        qDebug() << "Could not open file for modification";
        return ;
    }

    f.write( " medved" );
    f.close();

    qDebug() << "File updated";
    doTest();
}

void doTest()
{
    const QString path = QString( "%1/%2" ).arg( QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() ).arg( name );
    QFileInfo info( path );

    qDebug() << "Last modified (real):  " << info.lastModified().toString( "hh:mm:ss" );
    qDebug() << "Last modified (model): " << model->lastModified( model->index( path ) ).toString( "hh:mm:ss" );
}
```

Comment: `emit myFileTreeView->dataChanged` what is that???

Comment: it is my uneducated attempt to broadcast that the specific row in the model of my custom `QTreeView` has had its data changed and needs to be updated, based on similar but different posts on the net. It does not do what I had hoped. I put it in there so you can see what I've tried.

Comment: Added code sample, that reproduce a problem.

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qdirmodel.html#refresh :)

Comment: Good find. Yes, that is the functionality I want, but `QDirModel` has been obsolete since Jan. 2010 (https://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2010/01/08/qdirmodel-is-now-obsolete-qfilesystemmodel-is-taking-the-job/). I wonder why the `refresh()` method was not implemented in `QFileSystemModel`.

Comment: It's obsolete but keeped in qt5. Feel free to use ;). It just words. The reason, why it's obsolete - is intensive using of system resources and low performance for big nub=mber of files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`QFileSystemWatcher`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qfilesystemwatcher.html) to track events for each file, when it necessary to update your model.

`QFileSystemWatcher` does not track an events because of performance issues. This is [known issue](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-2276). So you may create your own model and/or use proposed workaround:

```
model.setRootPath("");
model.setRootPath("the_folder_you_want_to_update");
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to `reset()` because it loses the state of the user's expanded nodes.  I _do_ have my own `QFileSystemModel` and will look into implementing `QFileSystemWatcher`.

Comment: I just readed https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qfilesystemmodel.html - there are remark, that QFileSystemModel already uses QFileSystemWatcher. So your promlem is in another place.

Comment: yes, I've learned that as well. I either need my custom `QFileSystemModel` to be aware of the filesystem changes or I need to update the index data manually. I am not sure how to do either :/

Comment: You don't need to update indexes manually. You doing something wrong. Could you provide code sample that reproduce your problem?

Comment: Added Steps to Reproduce, per your request.  Thanks! :)

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. I've tried resetting the root path as you've suggested, but for some reason it only works inconsistently. I will accept this answer as it unblocks and is probably close to a full solution (or workaround for Qt). If I have time, I will look further into the inconsistency, but I have to table my implementation as it has lost priority for my upcoming release. Thanks again for all your help! :)